# server domain Openfire

Tags: android, openfire, asmack

i'm developing a android app which uses asmack to connect to a openfire xmpp server and i'd like to know if there is somehow to get the server domain, because i want to register new users using the domain as login but i don't wanna that the domain string is hard coded i want to connect to the server and get the server domain, i searched it already and i've tried to find some method in asmack connection that could provide me that but i didn't find any, and i didn't find any code our ideia on how to do that. Could someone help me with that ?Is there any method in smack/asmack api which could be usede to achie that ?!

Answer (score 1):

Call **`XMPPConnection.getServiceName()`** after logged in,  if that's what you wanted. And please be sure the domain name is configured correctly at server side (i.e. you can see it on the Openfire console page).